# Regex: How to override global case sensitive modifier when I cannot delete it?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
/I_CAN_MODIFY_ONLY_THIS/i
```

I cannot delete `i` global modifier. The only thing I can do is put something in place of `I_CAN_MODIFY_ONLY_THIS`. Is there a way to override global case insensitiveness?

Something like this apparently exists: `(?i)caseless(?-i)cased(?i)caseless`, but I cannot make it work. [source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

**Edit:** 
Apparently inline mode modifiers does not work in the regex engine I need to use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called "inline mode modifiers"

If you've tried, and it didn't work then sadly I think the simple answer is no.

There are different flavors/engines/implementations, and some support this and others don't. So it all depends how is the regex being run.

Some support it just at the start, overriding any listed outside, while others support placing in the middle of the regex.

On the same site you linked to, they provide a comparison of Flavors - from here I quickly compiled this list:

## Inline Mode Modifier Support

**Start or middle:** Python

**Just at start:** JGsoft, .NET, Java, Perl, PCRE, PCRE2, PHP, Delphi, R, XRegExp, Ruby, Boost (ECMA), Tcl ARE

**Not at all:** Javascript, VBScript, std::Regex, POSIX BRE, GNU BRE, GNU ERE, Oracle, XML, XPath

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override the global case in-sensitiveness by using the inline case-sensitive flag `(?-i)`. So, the *regex* for this would be

```
(?-i)i_can_modify_only_this
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/c1KND5/1)

Comment: They mention in their question that they have tried this and it's not working

Comment: but they include an example to show that they do know how to use

Comment: Sorry for confusion guys! I was hoping that I am using it wrong and it is possible to pull it off.